# Installing a new cartridge results in water being blocked completely

Tags: plumbing, faucet, cartridge

I am trying to install this new delta 3S-11H cartridge, but every time I do so and I turn on the knobs, the water is completely blocked by the cartridge for some reason. It happens for both hot and cold, and the water runs normally if I just turn it on with everything removed.

What could be the cause? I am already lining it up like I am supposed to be doing with both stems aligned, once I put the cartridge in, but before putting back the nut in.

Any help would be appreciated, here are some pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct cartridges for your faucet? Are they labeled specifically hot and cold, (side specific)  have you tried switching them?  "*and the water runs normally if I just turn it on with everything removed.*"  How does that work, **everything removed?**

Comment: Well I do have the same issues even if I try to put back the old cartridge, plus, I took it with me to home depot and they showed me the right one, but they only had the hot version of it. I ordered the cold one, so I will have it delivered in a few days. So I am fairly confident it should be the right one.



By everything removed, I meant taking out the cog, cartridge, everything and then opening the water valve, results in water running normally out of the empty hole.